# How to undo maximize view in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Pressing `Shift+Space` will maximize the view (for example, the Scene, Game or Inspector View) but in order to go back to the previous layout, I need to press a `⋮` in the top right corner and tick off a `Maximize` option.

[image]

Is it possible to do it using a keyboard shortcut?

I am using Personal version of Unity 2021.3.9f1 (LTS) on Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press SHIFT+SPACE again, and it can go back to the previous layout.

Comment: Oh... Strange. It works only sometimes not every time. It's like I have to be focused on something.